# Aligning data label to the center of bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need help to align the data labels for my bar graph in ggplot to the center of each bar just above the bar. Also month in the X axis are repeating. Kindly find my ggplot code for my shiny app below,

```
ggplot(data = chart_m, aes(x = `Reporting Month`, y = `Total tags generating alert`, fill = HSL)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = 'dodge') +
    geom_text(aes(label = `Total tags generating alert`), position = position_dodge(width = .9), vjust = -.1, size = 6) +
    scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%y")) +
    theme_grey()
```

For your reference i have attached the image. I need all the data labels to be aligned to each of the bar in the center.

[image: ggplot]

expected output

[image]

Any inputs appreciated.

Regards,
Mohan

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2) could be useful.

Comment: I would have pointed to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018499/how-to-put-labels-over-geom-bar-for-each-bar-in-r-with-ggplot2?rq=1

Comment: @DeveauP Hi Dev, I followed the details of your link in my code. As you can see my code it is same as your link. But the only difference is that my x axis has the month values in date format which is implemented through scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%y"))  code. As I am using date value my data labels are not aligning correctly.

Comment: Dates and `position_dodge` take some work to dodge on the correct scale.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351773/r-and-ggplot-changing-x-axis-to-date-removes-position-dodge) for an example.

Comment: @aosmith Thanks for the details.... I have written the below code for adjusting the details.   ggplot(data = chart_m, aes(x = `Reporting Month`, y = `Total tags generating alert`, fill = HSL)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = 'dodge') +
    geom_text(aes(label = `Total tags generating alert`), position = position_dodge(.9), vjust = -.02, hjust = .5,  size = 6) +
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", labels = date_format("%b-%y"))    But, when i select multiple month values i am getting the original output screen shot which is not correct. one month correct selected correct

Comment: It will be difficult for folks to help further without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  Consider adding an example dataset to your question.